# Convertir Foreing Key a Many to Many

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Actualmente tengo un código que funciona perfecto con un campo de 1 a 1 pero se requiere de 1 a N.

Es decir un proveedor puede pertenecer a muchas categorías, mi código:

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado=models.IntegerField(default='1')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Proveedor(models.Model):

    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ruc=models.CharField(max_length=13, default='9999999999')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    nombre_contacto = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cont_especial = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    estado = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    obligadoContabilidad = models.IntegerField(choices=contabilidadChoice, default=No)
    tipoPersona = models.IntegerField(choices=tipoPersonaChoice, default=Natural)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.razon_social
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def CrearProveedor(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        #form_proveedor  = ProveedorForm(request.POST)
        razon = request.POST.get('razon')
        ruc = request.POST.get('ruc')
        proveedor = Proveedor.objects.filter(Q(razon_social=razon) | Q(ruc=ruc)).count()

        if proveedor == 0:

            proveedor   = Proveedor(
                razon_social =razon,
                ruc=ruc,
                direccion=request.POST.get('direccion'),
                nombre_contacto=request.POST.get('nombre_contacto'),
                telefono=request.POST.get('telefono'),
                correo=request.POST.get('correo'),
                estado=request.POST.get('estado'),
                categoria_id=request.POST.get('categoria'),
                codigo=request.POST.get('codigo'),
                cont_especial=request.POST.get('cont_especial'),
                obligadoContabilidad=request.POST.get('obligadoContabilidad'),
                tipoPersona=request.POST.get('tipoPersona'),
            )
            proveedor.save()

            # mensaje exitoso
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Registro Creado Existosamente !!')

            return redirect('proveedores:administrar_proveedores')

        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'El registro ya existe.. no puede ser creado !!')

            return redirect('proveedores:administrar_proveedores')
    else:
        return redirect('logout')
```

`template`:

```
<!-- modal crear  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalProveedor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalProveedor" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{% url 'proveedores:crear_proveedor' %}" method="POST" id="form_crearProveedor" autocomplete="off">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><span class="badge bg-green">Proveedor</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="razon social" class="value_required">Razón Social:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="razon" id="razon" class="form-control uppercase" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ruc" class="value_required">RUC:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ruc" id="ruc" class="form-control only_int_numbers" required="" onblur="validarDocumento($(this).val());" maxlength="13">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control uppercase">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Código:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="{{ codigo }}" readonly="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Cont. Especial:</label>
                            <select name="cont_especial" class="form-control" id="cont_especial">
                              <option value="1">Si</option>
                              <option value="0">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contacto">Contacto:</label>
                            <input name="nombre_contacto" id="nombre_contacto" class="form-control uppercase" maxlength="100" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contacto">Teléfono:</label>
                            <input name="telefono" id="telefono" class="form-control uppercase" maxlength="100" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contacto" >Correo:</label>
                            <input name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control" maxlength="10" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contacto">Categoría:</label>
                           <select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="form-control">
                               {% for c in categoria_list %}
                               <option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.nombre }}</option>
                               {% endfor %}
                           </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Estado">Obligado Contabilidad</label>
                            <select name="obligadoContabilidad" class="form-control" id="obligadoContabilidad">
                              <option value="1">Si</option>
                              <option value="0" selected="">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Estado">Tipo</label>
                            <select name="tipoPersona" class="form-control" id="tipoPersona">
                              <option value="0">Natural</option>
                              <option value="1">Juridica</option>
                              <option value="2">Sociedad</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Estado">Estado:</label>
                           <select name="estado" required="true" class="form-control" id="estado">
                              <option value="1">Activo</option>
                              <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <p class="text-red">*Campos Obligatorios</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o">&nbsp;Grabar Datos</i>
                </button>
                <!-- pull-left determina posicion-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-close">&nbsp; Salir</i>
                </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿Como se debería grabar las múltiples categorías? Gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: No le encuentro sentido a tu pregunta, no la entiendo, explica mas detalladamente cual es tu problema o duda.

Comment: Saludos, actualmente un proveedor solo pertenece a una categoria, pero ahora se desea cambiar que un proveedor pertenesca a varias categorias es decir 1 a N categorias..

Comment: No lo entiendo aun, ya tienes una relación uno a muchos, es decir "una categoría no puede tener mas de un proveedor y un proveedor puede tener varias categorías". En dado caso que quieras que una categoría pueda tener mas de un proveedor tendrías que tener una relación muchos a muchos (`ManyToManyField`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos postearé lo que me ayudo.

**Situación:** Tengo una tabla **Proveedores** y otra **Categoria** donde un proveedor  pertenece a una categoria, bien ahora se desea hacer un cambio con datos en producción donde un **Proveedor** puede poseer/tener varias **Categorias**.

**Models actual:**

```
class Categoria(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado=models.IntegerField(default='1')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Proveedor(models.Model):

    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ruc=models.CharField(max_length=13, default='9999999999')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    nombre_contacto = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cont_especial = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    estado = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    obligadoContabilidad = models.IntegerField(choices=contabilidadChoice, default=No)
    tipoPersona = models.IntegerField(choices=tipoPersonaChoice, default=Natural)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.razon_social
```

Para realizar este cambio se deberá usar la relación ManytoMany algo así:

```
categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="old_categoria")
categorias = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
```

Con este cambio en el models debemos hacer:

```
./manage.py makemigrations proveedores
./manage.py migrate proveedores
```

como sabemos Django creará una tabla para almacenar dichas categorias de nuestra relación por lo tanto debemos buscar un metodo para pasar las categorias de foreingkey hacia la nueva relación, para esto se debe realizar:

```
./manage.py makemigrations proveedores --empy
```

con esto se crea un archivo de migración vacio en el cual deberemos agregar un método forward algo así:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

def forward(apps, schema_editor):
    Proveedor = apps.get_model("proveedores", "Proveedor")
    for proveedor in Proveedor.objects.all():
        proveedor.categorias.add(proveedor.categoria)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('proveedores', '0008_auto_20190723_2036'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forward)
    ]
```

ya con este cambio podemos realizar :

```
./ manage.py migrate proveedores
```

lo que hará internamente **Django** sera traspasar o copiar tanto el **ID** del **Proveedor** como de la **Categoria** relacionada hacia la nueva tabla de mi relación **ManyToMany** .

finalmente ya con esto podemos remover el campo(field) de nuestra relación vieja es decir remover:

```
categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name=""old_categoria)
```

una vez removido de mi **models.py**  debemos hacer:

```
./manage.py makemigrations proveedores
./manage.py migrate proveedores
```

Con esto ya tendremos el cambio realizado ha nivel de base de datos sin haber perdido información.

**Grabar datos de ManyToMany**

Teniendo lo siguiente en mi form template:

```
<form ...>
...
...

 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="contacto">Categoría(s):</label>
     <select name="categorias" id="categorias" class="form-control" multiple="">
     {% for c in categoria_list %}
     <option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.nombre }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

Como podemos notar es una selección multiple la misma para obtener en mi **views.py** deberemos hacer algo así:

```
categorias_list = request.POST.getlist('categorias')
```

con los datos provenientes del **POST** podemos grabar algo asi:

```
 with transaction.atomic():
   proveedor = Proveedor(
    ...
    ..
    )
    proveedor.save()

   for c in categorias_list:
     proveedor.categorias.add(c)
```

con esto básicamente graba el proveedor como las categorías respectivas seleccionadas.

Eso seria todo espero sirva a futuras consultas como referencia.